# multiply facets in tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Use ROR 4.01, elasticsearch and the tire gem.

Article model

```
class Article
 belongs_to: region
 belongs_to: house
end

def self.search(params)
    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      filter :term, region_id: params[:region_id] if params[:region_id].present?
      filter :term, house_id: params[:house_id] if params[:house_id].present?

      facet "regions" do
        terms :region_id
      end

      facet "houses" do
        terms :house_id
      end

    end  
  end
```

Article controller

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @articles = Article.search(params)
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
end
```

Article index view

```
%h3 Regions
          %ul
          - @articles.facets['regions']['terms'].each do |facet|
            %li
              = link_to_unless_current Region.find(facet['term']).name, params.merge(region_id: facet['term'])
              - if params[:region_id] == facet['term'].to_s
                (#{link_to "remove", region_id: nil})
              - else
                (#{facet['count']})
          %h3 House Owners
          %ul
          - @articles.facets['houses']['terms'].each do |facet|
            %li
              = link_to_unless_current House.find(facet['term']).name, params.merge(house_id: facet['term'])
              - if params[:house_id] == facet['term'].to_s
                (#{link_to "remove", house_id: nil})
              - else
                (#{facet['count']})
```

Filtering/facets on article based on regions or house owners works. But not both. How can it work together?

So working with multiply facets? is that possibly?

Thanks

remco

Answer (score 1):

[tire is deprecated](https://github.com/karmi/retire#tire) and not supported on current Elasticsearch versions, so I'm going from memory and the source code here, but...

`terms` should accept an array of terms.

You should thus be able create a facet with both terms:

```
  facet "houses_regions" do
    terms [:house_id, :region_id]
  end
```